# Write one value in attribute table until condition is met, then write another value

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table

I'm trying to make groups of points, based on bearring changes. I managed to find turning points (turn = 1), but no luck with grouping. The idea is to write value of 1 in "line_group" until there is value 1 in "turn", then write value 2 in "line_group" until there is value 1 in "turn" and so on...

[image]

Comment: Your point seem to be ordered by the "NPK_2" field is that the case ? if yes does that mean that all point up to "NPK_2"=71 belong to one group then from "NPK_2"=72 another group begin ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use PyQGIS for this:

```py
# SETTINGS:
layer = iface.activeLayer() # the layer to work with
turnfield = 'turn' # the fieldname of your turn field
groupfield = 'group' # the fieldname of your group field
groupcounter = 1 # the number of your groups to start with

# NO CHANGES NEEDED:
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures(): # sorted by feature ID, you could also do a request to change the iteration order
        if feat[turnfield] is not None: # you could also use: if feat[turnfield] == 1:
            groupcounter += 1
        feat[groupfield] = groupcounter
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with QGIS expressions - see below a step by step explanation how the expression works.

[image]

This is the expression to use:

```
with_variable (  -- step 3
    'array',
    array_sort (  -- step 2
        aggregate(  -- step 1
            @layer,
            'array_agg',
            NPK_2,
            turn=1
        )
    ),
    array_min(  -- step 6
        array_filter (  -- step 5
            array_foreach (  -- step 4
                @array,
                if (
                    NPK_2 < @element,
                    array_find( 
                        @array,
                        @element
                    )+1,
                    array_find( 
                        @array,
                        array_max (@array)
                    )+2
                )
            ), 
            @element>0
        )
    )
)
```

### Step by step explanation:

Also see the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html) to find detailed description of each function of QGIS expressions.

**Creating a variable representing the array of all NPK_2 values of turning points (lines 1 to 10 and 30)**

1. `aggregate()` (line 4 to 9): create an array of all NPK_2 values for which turn = 1. The result in my example looks like: `[ 97, 77, 71, 93, 91, 87, 83 ]`
2. `array_sort()` (line 3 to 10, enclosing the output of step 1): sort this array. Result: `[ 71, 77, 83, 87, 91, 93, 97 ]`
3. `with_variable()` (line 1 to 10 , enclosing the output of step 2, and ending on the very last line): create this array as a variable called `@array`. This variable saves the output of step 2 and calling `@array` returns `[ 71, 77, 83, 87, 91, 93, 97 ]`. Creating the variable is to avoid repeating the same expresion (steps 1 and 2) several times and thus to make the whole expression shorter.

**Evaluate each element of the array (variable) (lines 11 to 29)**

4. `array_foreach()` (line 13 to 26, refering to the output of step 3 on line 14, 18, 22, and 23 using the variable `@array`): for each element of the array, run a loop with an `if` clause (line 15 to 25): if the value of NPK_2 is smaller then the current element from the array (line 16), then return the position (index) of this element in the array (line 17 to 20) - as array's indices are 0 based (first element is 0), add 1 to get 1 for the first one. Otherwise, return the position (index) of the highest value in the array, adding 1 (as before, arrays are 0 based) and again 1 to get a value higher after the last turn - so totally adding 2 (lines 21 to 24):

   Thus using this loop, for all NPK_2 values smaller than 71 (..., 68, 69, 70), it returns 1: these values are smaller then 71 (first element of the array), thus get the elements index in the array, here the first position : `1`.

   The output of this depends on which feature is evaluated. For feature 16 e.g. output is

   ```
   [ NULL, NULL, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
   ```
5. `array_filter()` (line 12 and 27-28, enclosing the output of step 4): remove the NULL values from the resulting array, thus for feature 16 you get: `[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]`
6. `array_min()` (line 11 and 29, enclosing the output of step 5): get the smallest value from this array - thus for feature 16, it returns `3`. That is the correct value as you can see in the screenshot above.